# Magento 2.2.4 No 'Subproducts Discount' dropdown on catalog price rule

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I created a new **catalog price rule** for bundle products. I selected bundle product sku in the **Conditions** tab.

I am trying to add discount to the products assigned to bundle products. For that i want to change **Subproducts Discount** to Yes, but that drop-down is not there.

Is there any setting in admin to enable that box on rule page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to add discount to the products assigned to bundle
>   products. For that i want to change Subproducts Discount to Yes, but
>   that drop-down is not there.
>
> **Is there any setting in admin to enable that box on rule page?**

To apply the discount amount to associated products, set Subproduct Discounts to “Yes.” Select the pricing structure, and enter the Discount Amount.

You create your discount method here:

_ **Apply**: Select discount method, which can be: Apply as percentage of original, Apply as fixed amount, Adjust final price to this percentage, Adjust final price to discount value.

_ **Discount amount**: select the amount of discount.

_ **Subproduct discounts**: Select Yes to enable discount for subproduct.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply but as i mentioned in my question that the Subproducts Discount dropdown is not there in the Actions tab. Please check the screenshot.

Comment: In 'Conditions' select the category of your associated simple products rather than parent bundle items.

Comment: i have bundle product, which is from different category and 5 simple products associated which are from 2 different categories. What i want is to have discount applied to all products assigned to the bundle product and this discount must not be available when these simple products are viewed separately.